# How to use IsolatedStorage in a C# Console Application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, openxml, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I have a console application which uses an OpenXml to generate spreadsheet documents.

I am trying to use IsolatedStorage as shown in the code below but it is erroring with a message of:

> Unable to determine application identity of the caller?

Here is how I am doing it:

```
    var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    IsolatedStorageFileStream rootFile = store.CreateFile(src);
    store.CreateDirectory(tgt);

        var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(rootFile, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, false);

        WorkbookPart workbookpart = doc.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        Sheets sheets = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        return doc;
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
{
 // above code is here
}
```

But again the DesignerProperties wasn't defined, I think this is because it is a ConsoleApp rather than an MVC or other UI based system.

Many thanks.

Comment: "This method can be used only when the application identity can be determined - for example, when the application is published through ClickOnce deployment or is a Silverlight-based application. If you attempt to use this method outside a ClickOnce or Silverlight-based application, you will receive an IsolatedStorageException exception, because the application identity of the caller cannot be determined." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getuserstoreforapplication(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perhaps IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly would work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straight-forward. As per MSDN:

> All assemblies associated with an application use the same isolated store when using this method. This method can be used only when the application identity can be determined - for example, when the application is published through ClickOnce deployment or is a Silverlight-based application. If you attempt to use this method outside a ClickOnce or Silverlight-based application, you will receive an IsolatedStorageException exception, because the application identity of the caller cannot be determined.

You can't use `GetUserStoreForApplication`, because your application is not defined by its URL, as is the case with Silverlight and ClickOnce applications. The usual console application has no application identity to use for such a scenario.

One way to handle this would be by using a different isolated storage, for example:

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore
(
 IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, 
 null, null
);
```

It helps to use strong named assemblies too - that provides a suitably unique identification of each assembly.